# Modify search in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, search

Is it possible to edit a search that I have made previously when using Google Maps on Android?

The situation I have sometimes is that I make a search in Google Maps but it doesn't quite give me the results I want - perhaps because I didn't use the correct term or because there was a typo in my search. Or perhaps the search works but I want to refine it. As an example, I might first try to search for a street name just to get an idea of where the street is. Then later I might want to repeat that same search but also including the house number on that street because I want to get directions to a specific building on that street.

When I open Google Maps and press the search button I can see my previous searches in the history but I don't see any way to edit, select or copy/paste them. If I touch the search in the history it just repeats the exact same search as before without giving me any opportunity to edit or refine it.

My workaround is to manually type the entire search phrase again with the modification I need, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device has a directional pad (or a trackball), then when you press down, the previous search key would show up in the search box and is editable.

Comment: Yes, I have an HTC Desire and this method works. Thank you!